# Range of decimal, double, integer, etc. data types?

Tags: c++, xml, rdf

XML and RDF data has certain data types like decimal, double and integer (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xmlschema-2-19991217/#decimal). What are the range of these data types.

I know that the range of decimal, double, integer in C++ is as given at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx. Do XML and RDF data types have the same range or are their ranges. If their ranges are different then what are their actual ranges?

Comment: No. XML is something interpreted. The limitation comes from whatever trying to interpret it (E,g, C++) and what types it assigns, not the XML itself.

Comment: @JohnMikaelGundersen XML structure varies, but for representing particular types of data, there can be legal forms and non-legal forms.  For instance, "2" will be a legal value for the datatype xsd:integer, but "2.4" won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xs:double and xs:float are defined by IEEE rules. See

> #### [3.3.5 double](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#double)
>
> The ·value space· of double contains the non-zero numbers  m × 2e ,
>   where m is an integer whose absolute value is less than 253, and e is
>   an integer between −1074 and 971, inclusive.

By contrast, the limits for xs:integer and xs:decimal are implementation-defined.

> Section 3.3.3: [Definition:]  decimal represents a subset of the real
>   numbers, which can be represented by decimal numerals. The ·value
>   space· of decimal is the set of numbers that can be obtained by
>   dividing an integer by a non-negative power of ten, i.e., expressible
>   as i / 10n where i and n are integers and n ≥ 0.
>
> Section 5.4: All ·minimally conforming· processors must support
>   decimal values whose absolute value can be expressed as i / 10^k,
>   where i and k are nonnegative integers such that i < 1016 and k ≤ 16
>   (i.e., those expressible with sixteen total digits).